# Loop create Models for ensemble classifier in Rapidminer

Tags: rapidminer

I have the following situation:

I have collected data of users clicking on many different buttons. I then want to classify users not used in the training set. A scaled down example:

- There are 20 buttons in an application
- For each of these buttons, I want to train a classifier
- A new user clicks on 5 buttons
- Based on these 5 clicks, I want to use 5/20 models to vote on the class of the user

I know how to loop to create the different models for the different buttons, but I am at a loss as to how to use only the models that I need in later steps. Is this feasible in Rapidminer?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you would need 20 models to classify - unless each button click has a unique set of features which you want to model. If all you are trying to do is identify a users class based on which 5 buttons they click, i would imagine a single model would be able to do that.

Be that as it may, have you tried Store operator to save each model? Your high level process could do this:

```
Model development
        **Validate** a model for a button
        **Store** it using a macro name specified for the button e.g. button1
Model application
Loop Until (all 20 buttons are completed)
        Retrieve Model for button1
        Apply Model 
        Store prediction
End loop
```